# Make a select statement output a number with commas

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and am trying to figure out how to make a select statement output a number separated by commas. I am only able to find how to transform a number into a number with commas, which isn't what I want. The following code is the code I am trying to get to output as a number with commas. Right now when you execute the statement it returns a value of 750000.00 and I want it to return 750,000.00.

Code:

```
select max(c.salary) as MaxSalary
from #Career c inner join
     #Member m
    on c.Member_ID = m.Member_ID
where m.age < 35
```

Comment: Number formatting is something you usually do in the _presentation layer_, not the data access layer. As the current answers imply, the solution, if done in SQL, is vendor-specific, version-specific and makes the query harder to read and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FORMAT()` for SQL Server 2012 onward

```
select FORMAT(750000.00, 'N', 'en-us') AS 'Numeric Format' 


declare @table table(salary decimal(16,4))
insert into @table
values
(1234.00),
(64423.55)

select FORMAT(sum(salary), 'N', 'en-us') AS 'Numeric Format' 
from @table

--or using your tables
select FORMAT(max(c.salary), 'N', 'en-us') AS 'Numeric Format' 
from #Career c inner join
     #Member m
    on c.Member_ID = m.Member_ID
where m.age < 35
```

Comment: but I don't want to do the following: 1) execute my code, 2) find the number that is outputs (in this case 750000), and then 3) use the code you just shared to convert the 750000. Instead I want to do that all in one step. Is it possible to do that with a subquery?

Answer (score 1):

This may be an old-fashioned way, but converting to money and then converting to a varchar is the traditional method:

```
select convert(varchar(255), convert(money, max(salary)), 1) as MaxSalary
```

Comment: but I don't want to do the following: 1) execute my code, 2) find the number that is outputs (in this case 750000), and then 3) use the code you just shared to convert the 750000. Instead I want to do that all in one step. Is it possible to do that with a subquery?

Comment: @BrynneColella . . . Just fill in the rest of the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Format if your dataset is minimal as below

```
select format(75000.00, 'N')
```

You can do that as below:

```
select Format(max(c.salary),'N') as MaxSalary
from #Career c inner join
  #Member m
  on c.Member_ID = m.Member_ID
where m.age < 35
```

Comment: but I don't want to do the following: 1) execute my code, 2) find the number that is outputs (in this case 750000), and then 3) use the code you just shared to convert the 750000. Instead I want to do that all in one step. Is it possible to do that with a subquery?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server 2012 +, the following will get you what you need:

```
  SELECT FORMAT([COLUMN], 'N#')
```

where # is the number of decimal places. Put N0 for 0, N2 for 2, etc.

SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
  SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(20), (CAST([COLUMN] AS MONEY)), 1), '.00', '')
```